# GameCenter request

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I have to following question.

In the apple documentation, there is the following clas methode

```
+(NSUInteger)maxNumberOfRecipients
```

How can I define this clas Methode to 5 for example.

I tried in my friendrequestcontroller the following code.

```
[friendRequestController.maxNumberOfRecipients  = 5];
```

But I always get the error

```
property 'maxNumberOfRecipients' not found on object of type 'GKFriendRequestComposeViewController*'
```

What did I wrong?

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
```

This one is implemented, so it should work!

thanks for your solutions!

joel

Comment: `[friendRequestController.maxNumberOfRecipients  = 5];` => You should read about Objective-C. Either your use `[]`, calling a method, either you use "=" to set. So, if `maxNumberOfRecipients` exists and has the correct setter: `[friendRequestController setMaxNumberOfRecipients:5];` or `friendRequestController.maxNumberOfRecipients  = 5;`
But, according to the code you quote, with a "+", it's a class method and not a instance method.

Comment: So how would you declare a class methode +(NSUInteger)maxNumberOfRecipients ? Because it sais that maxNumberOfRecipients property is not defined on object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is right :) you can't set maxNumberOfRecipients. It's a read-only class with which you can merely "determine the maximum number if recipients" according to the [iOS Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKFriendRequestComposeViewController_Ref/Reference/Reference.html). If you need to add more recipients, you need to make multiple requests.